# Browser won't set HTTP-only cookie AXIOS response?

Tags: vue.js, express, cookies, axios, http-headers

**Client**

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-type'] = "application/json"
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:5000'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
const resp = await axios.post('/auth/login',{user:user},{
withCredentials: true })
```

**Server**

```
app.use(cors({
    origin:['http://<clienturl>'],
    credentials: true,
}))

response...

const cookieOptions={
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'none',
    path:'/'
 }

res.cookie("auth", tokenstring , cookieOptions)
        .send(ApiResponse.success("Voila!"))
```

in the Network tab I see
login (preflight)
login (xhr) : I can see in response headers Set-Cookie: auth=token

but no cookie in Cookies being set no matter if it's httpOnly or not...

Pay attention: Client-Server different origin.

Comment: Cookies with `SameSite=None` are only set if they are also `Secure`. Hence they won't be set in your development environment.

Comment: Still not set even if secure is true :(

Comment: A `Secure` cookie is only set if the server uses HTTPS. Can you achieve that in your development environment?

Comment: Hey thanks for quick answers. I am not sure how to set that in vite/vue client

Comment: Then don't use `SameSite=None` is the development environment, but leave it out.

Comment: Yes but what I can tell , then Chrome refuses to set cookie(SameSite defaults to LAX)  which prevents the cookie from being set in a cross-site context. Am I missing something here.

Comment: You are right. Sorry, then you must try HTTPS.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately..Thanks anyways!